# Como desplegar una variable en un tag p en react?

Tags: html, reactjs

Tengo un pequeño problema, este surge cuando intento desplegar una variable... o mejor dicho un atributo de un json en un tag p, este no aparece por ningun lado, nunca se llega a mostrar la informacion que este contiene.

Segun yo tengo entendido la manera correcta de insertarlo seria:

```
<div className="col-md-6 d-flex flex-row">
   <p>Costo: Q.{general_info.costo}</p>
</div>
```

pero no desplega nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no se que mas hacer ya que si uso un input de la siguiente forma:

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label>Costo</label>
    <input value={general_info.costo} />
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

habra algun metodo para mostrar la informacion o yo estoy haciendo algo mal?
Deibo de aclarar tambien que la informacion se esta mandando a traer desde un backend usando useEffect() y general_info se esta usando con useState, puede sera algo que se me esta olvidando?

Comment: ¿Si haces un `console.log(general_info)`, el resultado es un JSON string o es un objeto? ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta el resultado de imprimir la información que estás intentando usar? Además, ¿podrías añadir como traes la información del backend?

Comment: la informacion que trae el backend, es solo costos y nombres y id, solo eso se manda a llamar, y si lo desplega como un JSON

Comment: Entonces te falta convertir ese JSON a un objeto. `general_info = JSON.parse(loQueVengaDelBackend)`

Comment: Puede afecta tambien que no lo estoy modelando? osea, crear la variable usando estados y solo mandarle "{}", tambine puede afectar?

Comment: No puedo saberlo con certeza. Por lo mismo te sugerí agregar tú código a la pregunta para tener más información sobre lo que está pasando.